# mod_log_sql_mysql : database connection error

Tags: mysql, apache, debian

I'm trying to use mod_log_sql to log access log in a mysql database. (The OS is Debian 10)
My database config is fine (double checked)... but it doesn't work and the error I get in the appache error.log is :

```
mod_log_sql_mysql: 
  database connection error: 
    mysql error: Unknown MySQL server host 'loguser' (-2)
```

My virtualhost.conf has the following:

LogSQLLoginInfo mysql://loguser:password@localhost:3306/apachelogs

Following the pattern driver://username[:password]@hostname[:port]/database

What is strange is that the error shows a confusion between the user and the host:

```
 params : Unknown MySQL server host 'loguser'
```

whereas 'loguser' is the username.

Any ideas where the problem comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload any code? I use:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

To make a connection.